# Running sudo restricted commands by creating soft link

Tags: security, sudo

I have `sudo` access to one of our test machines and the following are the commands restricted for me:

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> sudo -l
user_sree's password:
User user_sree may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL, (ALL) !/bin/sh, !/bin/bash, !/bin/ksh, (ALL) !/bin/su, (ALL) !/usr/bin/passwd, !/usr/sbin/useradd, !/usr/sbin/userdel, !/usr/sbin/usermod,
    !/usr/sbin/visudo
```

Which says I cannot run `visudo` or `/usr/sbin/visudo`. And I confirmed this:

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> sudo /usr/sbin/visudo
Sorry, user user_sree is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/visudo' as root on sel8585.
```

Now, out of curiosity I created a symlink to `/usr/sbin/visudo`:

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/visudo myvi`
```

I tried accessing the sudoers file by calling this soft link and it works fine.

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> sudo /home/user_sree/myvi
myvi: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
```

Similarly I was able to able to run other restricted commands by creating softlinks.

If I am to configure `sudo` for others, how can I stop others from doing this? I do not want to restrict them creating softlinks.

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> sudo -l | grep bash
    (ALL) ALL, (ALL) !/bin/sh, !/bin/bash, !/bin/ksh, (ALL) !/bin/su, (ALL) !/usr/bin/passwd, !/usr/sbin/useradd, !/usr/sbin/userdel, !/usr/sbin/usermod,
```

Similarly:

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> sudo sh -c 'ls'
Sorry, user user_sree is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/sh -c ls' as root on sel8585.
```

Now with the symlink `mybash` linked to `/bin/bash`: (in my system `/usr/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`)

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> sudo /home/user_sree/mybash -c 'ls'
```

bin  mybash  myvi  sudoers.back  test.pp

```
user_sree@sel8585:~> ll my*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user_sree users  9 Jul 16 14:10 mybash -> /bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user_sree users 16 Jul 16 14:13 myvi -> /usr/sbin/visudo
```

P.S:

```
Cmnd_Alias   NSHELLS = /bin/sh,/bin/bash,/bin/ksh
Cmnd_Alias   NSU = /bin/su
Cmnd_Alias   NCMDS = /usr/bin/passwd,/usr/sbin/useradd,/usr/sbin/userdel,/usr/sbin/usermod,/usr/sbin/visudo

user_sree ALL=(ALL) ALL, !NSHELLS, !NSU, !NCMDS
```

The above are the entries in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be honest, if you're going to allow users to run everything except a few commands, you're going to run into problems.

For example, you're disallowing access to the `user*` commands yet users can still run `vipw` or even just edit the password and shadow files using a text editor. And if you lock down access to `vi` for example, what's to prevent them installing a different text editor and using that? Or even using `cat` or the shell builtin `echo` to add a new user?

You're never going to be able to give `sudo` access to "everything except these few commands". Rather, remove the `ALL` entry, define what's allowed and give access only to those allowed commands.